# Dropwizard/Jersey sub-resource chaining

Tags: jersey, dropwizard

I am building REST service using Dropwizard 8.2.0. I have 2 resources: FolderResource and FileResource:

```
@Path("folder")
public class FolderResource {

   @Path("{name}/file")            
   public FileResource getFileResource() {
      return new FileResource();
   }
}

public class FileResource() {
   @GET
   @Path("{id}")
   @Produces("application/json")
   public Response getFileInfo() {
        return Response.ok().entity("{}").build();
   }
}
```

The intention here is that when "folder/xyz/file/5" is called, getFileInfo() method will be invoked.
This Jersey feature is described here:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2464

However when embedded in Dropwizard not only getFileInfo() not called, the getFileResource() function also not being invoked.
If I add @GET annotation to getFileResource() method, then it does get called, but returns FileResource JSON representation which is of course not the goal and is contrary to the documentation that clearly states that method should NOT be annotated with method designators.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

`@Path("folder")` and `@Path("{name}/file")` results in `folder{name}/file`.

You need to add a slash in between, i.e. `@Path("/{name}/file")`. You'll have the same issue on `getFileInfo` as well, so rename it to `@Path("/{id}")`.